# scikit-learn's KFold method makes my RAM explodes

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, memory-management, google-colaboratory

Thanks for visiting.
I am making deep learning model for time series segmentation using Colab(has 12GiB RAM capacity)

**The problem I met was**, whenever I try to split my training data for K-Fold Cross Validation using `sklearn.model_selection.KFold` instance, the system allocates new memory for newly seperated data.
And that causes memroy explosion.

#### So, how can I use this `KFold` instance without creating new memory allocation?

Maybe I could just use slicing to split my dataset which doesn't creates new memory, but I am pretty sure that I am missing something.

Codes below are my memory check results.

1. Using KFold instance for split(new memory allocation)

```py
X = pd.read_parquet(X_PATH).to_numpy()    
Y_gt = pd.read_parquet(Y_PATH).to_numpy()
# Memory consumption after loading, <7.3 GiB>

kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False)
for fold, (train_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):

    x_train, x_test = X[train_idx], X[test_idx]
    y_train, y_test = Y_gt[train_idx], Y_gt[test_idx]   
    # After above, <10.7 GiB>

    del x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test
    # After deleting reference, <9.6 GiB>
    gc.collect()
    # After garbage collection, <7.4 GiB>
    break
```

2. Using Slicing for split(no memory allocation)

```py
# before slicing, mermoy consumption: 7.5GiB
x_train, x_test = X[:200], X[200:]
y_train, y_test = Y_gt[:200], Y_gt[200:]
# after slicing, mermoy consumption: 7.5GiB
```

I used Colab environment which has
`python 3.10.12   tensorflow 2.13.0   sklearn 1.2.2   numpy 1.23.5`

Thank you very much for your attention.